# Выбор sql с массива строк не работает

Tags: node.js, select, mariadb

У меня есть массив значений `let arr = ['val1', 'val2']` Я хочу выбрать рядки у которых один из параметров совпадает со значением из массива. В таблице у меня есть 3 поля (Айди второе значения типа числа, и третее строки). Если я вибираю по значению типа число l`et arr = [12, 15]`, и передаю массив чисел, все работает отлично, но если я передаю массив слов

```
pool.query("select id from sometable where somerow in (" + arr + ")", 
      function (err, rows) {
                if (err) return console.log(err)
                console.log(rows)
            })
```

получаю такую ошибку

> `'Unknown column \'val1\' in \'where clause\'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо экранировать значения массива, например так:

```
pool.query("select id from sometable where somerow in (" + "'"+arr.join("','")+"'"+ ")", 
      function (err, rows) {
                if (err) return console.log(err)
                console.log(rows)
            })
```

Но вообще, лучше использовать что то типа knex или orm типа sequelize